# Negative Voltage Generator for Low Voltage ( +1V ) Input

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, circuit-design

I am working on an analog circuit. I can only use a +1V power supply. My design requires a negative rail, so that my level shifter will work.

Attempts:

> I have already seen [Build Your Own Negative Voltage Generator](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/build-your-own-negative-voltage-generator/)
>   and I cannot use this because a diode would eat up 0.7 V. A Schottky would still eat up ~0.1 to 0.3V.

I need some way to get a near perfect way of converting input +1V to a ( -0.9 to -1 V ) output.

Comment: How much do you care about low current draw?

Comment: What are you using for the power supply? Is a positive rail required as well?

Comment: Low current draw is not a concern. I have a positive 1V rail already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most analog circuits work better on a bit higher voltage than 1V. If you use a single cell charge pump or inductor step-up to, say, 2.7 or 3.3V then you can use an inverting charge pump to get -2.7 or -3.3V. Of course the current draw will be multiplied by the voltage ratio plus losses.

Eg. LTC1502-3.3 + LM2776.

Comment: I cannot find a SPICE model for this. Do you have any suggestions on how to simulate this?

Comment: LTC1502 has a SPICE model. LM2776 has one that apparently doesn't work in LTspice. If you absolutely need to simulate it, try an LTC1044 under LTspice instead of the latter. TC7660 is similar.

Comment: You were right. LTC1502-3.3 and LTC1044 models are already built into LTSpice.